# Opening Form (.cs) in Design View in Visual Studio Shows Unsaved Changes Immediately

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-express

I have a form in a C# project that behaves oddly when opened in "Design" view.  Whenever I open the form in "Design" view, it immediately puts an asterisk (*) beside the name of the form on its tab.  If I close it without having made any changes, I am prompted to save the changes.  Only one form does this.

If I open the code for the form directly, it does not behave this way. If I open the designer code directly, it does not behave this way.

However, there is one odd sequence that I can replicate:

1. Open the designer code (shows no asterisk)
2. Open the form in "Design" view (now both tabs have an asterisk)

   - a. If I try to close either tab now, I am asked to save changes
   - b. If I close Visual Studio, I am asked to save changes for both tabs (or all 3 if I had both the designer code and the form code open before opening the form in "Design" view).
3. Switch to designer code tab.  When I do this, the "Undo" button enables and I have the option to undo "Designer Generated Code".  BUT, *the asterisk goes away at this point* for only the designer code tab.

   - a. If I undo the changes, copy the code, redo the changes, and compare the code, they are identical.
4. I can now close the designer tab without being asked to save changes.  The "Design" view tab still has an asterisk and asks to save changes, though.  It also still has the "Undo" button enabled with the option to undo "Designer Generated Code"

How do I stop these phantom (not-actually-) changes from being (not-actually-) made when I open the form in "Design" view?

Note: I have nothing fancy or non-standard about my setup.  Single developer on same machine every time, everything saves to VS's default locations, no 3rd party anything of any kind involved with VS.

Comment: Is the code in source control? If so (and it should be) what differences (if any) are there between the version in source control and the local version once you've saved the changes?

Comment: @ChrisF There's no source control being used, unfortunately.

Comment: In that case take a copy of the current version before opening the project. Then open and save. Compare these two versions. The problem might be that the designer is formatting the code (or swapping spaces for tabs or vice versa) and doing a copy/paste applies those formatting rules as well - hence the reason why you didn't find any changes.

Comment: This is most likely a component that does some initialization that triggers this. Many complex component libraries have these symptoms, we're seeing this with several DevExpress controls (although I can't pinpoint exactly which one it is) and I've also seen it with other libraries. In the cases where this happens, when we save the files and compare with version control, there are no differences.

Comment: Looking at the differences between the old and the new Designer.cs file is the most obvious way to narrow it down.  Most commonly it is because the form's AutoScaleMode, it works at design-time as well.  The form adapts itself to your monitor's DPI setting.  But anything is possible, code inside controls can run at design-time and that can change property values that force the Designer.cs file to be regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with form designer it use CodDom to generate code in Designer.cs file.once you open up the designer and designer.cs file. the operation you perform while designing the form UI CodeDome will generate a code in a designer file and it will show the * sign.
To make it Short at the end there is a designer.cs file which will actually reflect the changes in the form designer.